# Is cardinality continuous?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let the underlying set theory be ZFC. Let $x_1 \subseteq x_2 \subseteq \dots$ and $y_1 \subseteq y_2 \subseteq \dots$ be ascending sequences of sets such that, for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, $|x_n| = |y_n|$. Is it the case that $\big|\cup_{n =1}^{\infty}x_n\big| = \big|\cup_{n =1}^{\infty}y_n\big|$? If this is not generally true, is it possible to characterize all those—or at least some interesting—cases for which this does hold? Is there a standard terminology for these cases? Can this be generalized to transfinite sequences? Does the answer change if we require that the sequences be strictly increasing, i.e. for every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, $x_n \subsetneq x_{n+1}$ and $y_n \subsetneq y_{n+1}$?

Comment: Relevant: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Infinite_Union_of_Infinite_Sets

Comment: This can surely fail in ZF, if $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets then you can pick $x_i$ all equal to $y_0$ and $y_i$ a sequence of countable sets whose union is $\Bbb R$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: If $\mathbb{R}$ were a countable union of countable sets, it would be countable, which it is not, since its cardinality is that of the powerset of the natural numbers. So I'm not sure what it is you intended to say.

Comment: A countable union of countable sets is countable needs some (weak) form of choice

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: As I wrote in my question, the underlying set theory is ZFC.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote a comment rather than an answer, just to give some context

Comment: In ZFC you can assume WLOG that every $x_i$ and $y_i$ is an ordinal. Then a counterexample would require the larger of the two unions to be a successor cardinal -- but it would have cofinality $\omega$, which is impossible; successor cardinals are always regular.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Can you please write this as an answer? And, if possible, try to keep it as simple as possible and explain the terms you use. My set theory is very rusty.

Comment: @EvanAad: I'll prefer to wait a bit; I have a hunch that the argument I have in mind is more convoluted that it needs to be, so let's see if someone can give a slicker one first.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: OK. Just to be clear: you think that cardinality is continuous without reservation, correct?

Comment: (For the transfinite case there are counterexamples; for example you can index your sequences by all the countable ordinals and let $x_\alpha=\omega+\alpha$ and $y_\alpha=\omega$. Then the union of the $x_\alpha$s is $\omega_1$ whereas that of the $y_\alpha$s is $\omega$. It's crucial for such counterexamples that the sequences are not required to be _strictly_ increasing, though.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: By "strictly increasing" do you mean that $x_n \subsetneq x_{n+1}$ or that $|x_n| < |x_{n+1}|$?

Comment: I mean in the $\subsetneq$ sense. (That I wrote "increasing" where you had "ascending" was an accident and not intended to convey a different meaning).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: And what if the sequences are strictly increasing?

Comment: @EvanAad: Then, as far as I can see offhand, the unions will necessarily be equinumerous even in the transfinite case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is always true.  If $x_1\subseteq x_2\subseteq\dots$ and $x=\bigcup x_n$, then $|x|=\sup_n|x_n|$, and in particular $|x|$ is uniquely determined by the sequence of cardinalities $|x_n|$.  Clearly $|x|\geq|x_n|$ for all $n$ so $|x|\geq\sup_n |x_n|$.  Conversely, $|x_n|\leq \sup|x_n|$ for all $n$ so $|x|\leq \aleph_0\cdot \sup|x_n|=\sup|x_n|$ as long as $\sup |x_n|$ is infinite (and if it is finite then the result is trivial).

Note that if you consider increasing sequences with possibly uncountable index sets then this is no longer true.  For instance, with index set $\omega_1$, if you let $x_\alpha=\omega+\alpha$ and $y_\alpha=\omega$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$, then $|x_\alpha|=|y_\alpha|=\aleph_0$ for each $\alpha$ but $\left|\bigcup x_\alpha\right|=\aleph_1$ while $\left|\bigcup y_\alpha\right|=\aleph_0$.   If you require the sequences to be strictly increasing then it is true though: letting $\kappa$ be the cofinality of the index set, the argument above shows that $|x|\geq\sup|x_i|$ and $|x|\leq \kappa\cdot\sup|x_i|=\max(\kappa,\sup|x_i|)$ but also $|x|\geq\kappa$ if the $x_i$ are strictly increasing (since looking at a cofinal well-ordered subsequence gives at least one new element of $x$ for each term in the subsequence), so $|x|=\max(\kappa,\sup|x_i|)$.

Comment: My set theory is very rusty. Could you please explain what the supremum of a set of cardinalities means? And how we know that it exists?

Comment: It means the same thing supremum always means: the least cardinal greater or than equal to all of them.  It exists because cardinals are well-ordered.